# How to change bluetooth timeout settings for bluetooth mouse

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, power-management

I have a Logitech MX Master 3 that I am using with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (kernel 5.4.0-58-generic). If the mouse sits idle for a short period (less than 30 seconds, though I haven't timed it precisely) it appears to enter a low-power state and only returns to normal operation after a couple of seconds of motion. This creates a pretty annoying visual "hitch" when you move the mouse after letting it sit idle for unreasonably short periods.

I have encountered this exact issue on Windows 10 w/ a different laptop (but the same mouse). On windows the fix is to use the device manager to disable the setting which allows the Bluetooth Controller to be put to sleep to save power. I am now trying to do the same thing on Ubuntu, with no luck so far.

From  [this reddit thread](https://redd.it/g432zt) I learned that the "timeout" setting in `/var/lib/bluetooth/{BT MAC]/{mouse MAC}/info` might be useful. On my system it is configured as follows:

```
[ConnectionParameters]
MinInterval=6
MaxInterval=9
Latency=44
Timeout=216
```

I tried setting the timeout to a large value (10000) and also to zero. After changing the value, I ran:

```
bluetoothctl power off
bluetoothctl power on
```

I observed no effect. I then tried changing the value and running:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

This had the effect of setting the value back to the default of `216`. With some random googling, I stumbled upon [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=248133) which seems to imply that `hcitool lecup` might be able to set the value so I tried:

```
sudo hcitool lecup --handle 3585 --timeout 0
```

Where 3585 is the handle of my mouse. This just produces `Could not change connection params: Input/output error(5)`.

I am not a deep linux expert, and am admittedly unfamiliar with the relationship between `bluetoothctl`, the bluetooth service, and `hcitool`. What I would like to know is:

1. How do I get the change to the `/var/lib/bluetooth/{BT MAC]/{mouse MAC}/info` file to take effect so I can test different values?
2. Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree - is there an easier way to just disable the bluetooth "sleeping" functionality?

Answer (score 10):

The issue you are facing is not related to the Bluetooth timeout but more likely the USB auto suspend feature built into the kernel.

I am running Arch and i have a Mx master 3 and i aslo experienced similar issue to what you described.

This is how i went about fixing it:

1. run command to find out the id of your bluetooth module

```
$ lsusb -vt

Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/4p, 12M
    ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
```

The id of my bluetooth module is 8087:0a2a

2. Create a udev rule to disable auto suspend for the module.

edit/create following file /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb_power_save.rules

and add this line

```bsh
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="8087", ATTR{idProduct}=="0a2a", ATTR{power/autosuspend}="-1"
```

after this reboot your pc and the lag should go away.

I used following links for reference.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#USB_autosuspend

https://fueledonbacon.com/popos-bluetooth-autosuspend-problem/

Comment: I can confirm this works also in my case with a Logitech MX Master 3 mouse under Kubuntu 20.04 LTS. Many thanks to @iambak for the right solution! This really should be the accepted answer. I have tried out many other different Bluetooth settings and nothing helped. Regardless what I have tried, the BT mouse was after the automatic screen-locker always inactive. In my case, the entire BT controller was disabled. **Note**, I have added the `Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)` ID to the file which is `0a5c:4500`. I don't have added here the ID of the 4 sub-devices.

Comment: @iambak Thank you so much, this also works pretty fine to me. I've a ```ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)``` and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Nice!

Comment: This fix works wonders with a Logitech MX Anywhere 3 Bluetooth mouse on Fedora 36. Thanks a lot, the jumpy cursor with Bluetooth mice was really driving me crazy on Linux.

Comment: @Clemens  I have the same problem, Mx anywhere 3 lag after the ideal time of 4-5 seconds, I don't have a dongle using Bluetooth. Do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: @Ashish Viradiya Unfortunately I didn't have found a perfect solution regarding the lag of the MX Anywhere 3 Mouse on certain systems. So I still have some sort of lags in conjunction with a BCM2046 BT controller. Interestingly this seems to be not a problem with an Intel 7260 BT controller. Maybe Logitech will fix this problem at some point via a firmware update or someone improves the Broadcom Bluetooth Linux driver. Alternatively the proprietary Logitech transceiver might help. The more complex way is to change the existing BT controller with a newer BT 5.x compliant model from Intel.

Comment: @AshishViradiya I’m using the built in Bluetooth not a dongle, I believe the built in Bluetooth module uses USB for connection so the same steps should apply. Try the steps and let us know how you go.

Comment: @iambak i have resolved the issue with Bluetooth mouse, by doing edit /etc/default/grub
 usbcore.autosuspend=-1 in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, and sudo update-grub , restart computer.

Comment: @iambak install TLPUI software in ubuntu, in that i have disabled: usb_autosuspend, usb_exclude_btusb and usb_exclude_phone, I hope this help.

Comment: @Clemens , I found my wifi was 2.5GzH frequency and mouse have the same, that was conflicting the communication. i have changed it to 5GhZ and solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to control this through the `IdleTimeout` setting in `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf`. It looks like this:

```
# Configuration file for the input service

# This section contains options which are not specific to any
# particular interface
[General]

# Set idle timeout (in minutes) before the connection will
# be disconnect (defaults to 0 for no timeout)
#IdleTimeout=30

...
```

Remove the `#` and set the timeout to something like 5. If you set it to zero, be ready to charge batteries on a much more regular basis. From there you can sign out and back in again to begin using the setting.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it appears to have no effect. It looks like the default is 0 for unlimited. I tried a value of 30 w/ no luck. I also am now trying the udev rule in the reddit thread linked above (it hasn't worked yet).