# Ubuntu 20.04: Bluetooth mouse is disconnecting and reconnecting every minute or so

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, logitech

Since 3 days ago, my Bluetooth mouse started disconnecting and reconnecting constantly.

I have tried a bunch of tricks with no luck.

I'm thinking the main issue line in journalctl is " (EE) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 28ms, your system is too slow" but I'm by no means an expert

Journalctl -f gives the following:

```
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Oct 12 21:34:08 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device removed
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 acpid[1176]: input device has been disconnected, fd 21
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "fd" "132"
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: not releasing fd for 13:82, still in use
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "fd" "132"
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (EE) systemd-logind: failed to release device: Device not taken
Oct 12 21:34:15 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0004: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 upowerd[1671]: treated changed event as add on /sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0004/power_supply/hidpp_battery_3
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0004/input/input25
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0004: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 (/dev/input/mouse2)
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 (/dev/input/event18)
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3'
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 systemd-logind[1215]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event18 (Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3)
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82 fd 132 paused 0
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: always reports core events
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a pointer
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a keyboard
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device removed
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: needs a virtual subdevice
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0004/input/input25/event18"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3" (type: MOUSE, id 16)
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a pointer
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a keyboard
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3'
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: always reports core events
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is a virtual subdevice
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0004/input/input25/event18"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3" (type: KEYBOARD, id 17)
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "dk"
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Oct 12 21:34:16 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device removed
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 acpid[1176]: input device has been disconnected, fd 21
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "fd" "132"
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: not releasing fd for 13:82, still in use
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "fd" "132"
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Oct 12 21:34:25 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0005: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x557aee708310] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x557af2615ee0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x557af01e5160] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 upowerd[1671]: treated changed event as add on /sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0005/power_supply/hidpp_battery_4
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0005/input/input26
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0005: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 (/dev/input/mouse2)
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 (/dev/input/event18)
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3'
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 systemd-logind[1215]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event18 (Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3)
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82 fd 132 paused 0
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: always reports core events
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a pointer
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a keyboard
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device removed
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: needs a virtual subdevice
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0005/input/input26/event18"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3" (type: MOUSE, id 16)
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a pointer
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a keyboard
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3'
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: always reports core events
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is a virtual subdevice
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0005/input/input26/event18"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3" (type: KEYBOARD, id 17)
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "dk"
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Oct 12 21:34:26 shack-ThinkPad-T490 gnome-shell[3505]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
^[[BOct 12 21:35:02 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (EE) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 24ms, your system is too slow
Oct 12 21:35:06 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (EE) client bug: timer event18 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-23ms), your system is too slow
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 sh[11838]: laptop-mode: Battery polling disabled
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 systemd[1]: lmt-poll.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 systemd[1]: Finished Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device removed
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 acpid[1176]: input device has been disconnected, fd 21
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "fd" "132"
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: not releasing fd for 13:82, still in use
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "fd" "132"
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Oct 12 21:35:13 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0006: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 upowerd[1671]: treated changed event as add on /sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0006/power_supply/hidpp_battery_5
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0006/input/input27
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 (/dev/input/mouse2)
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0006: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 (/dev/input/event18)
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3'
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 systemd-logind[1215]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event18 (Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3)
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82 fd 132 paused 0
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: always reports core events
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a pointer
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a keyboard
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device removed
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: needs a virtual subdevice
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0006/input/input27/event18"
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3" (type: MOUSE, id 16)
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a pointer
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) event18 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device is a keyboard
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3'
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: always reports core events
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Oct 12 21:35:14 shack-ThinkPad-T490 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3260]: (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: is a virtual subdevice
```

Dmesg gives the following:

```
[  334.922603] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[  337.885598] input: MX Master 3 Keyboard as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0001/input/input19
[  337.886103] input: MX Master 3 Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0001/input/input20
[  337.886777] hid-generic 0005:046D:B023.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
[  338.071399] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0001: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[  338.461852] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0001/input/input22
[  338.462779] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
[  366.556672] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0002: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[  367.381865] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0002/input/input23
[  367.382104] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0002: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
[  559.540222] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0003: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[  560.350508] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0003/input/input24
[  560.351402] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0003: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
[  567.459853] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0004: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[  568.254964] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0004/input/input25
[  568.255424] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0004: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
[  577.442751] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0005: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[  578.260582] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0005/input/input26
[  578.261445] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0005: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
[  625.577860] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0006: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[  626.087790] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B023.0006/input/input27
[  626.158111] logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.0006: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.15 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3] on 24:41:8c:2f:d0:22
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the battery?

Comment: It doesn't have replaceable battery, but charging it seemed to do the trick.
Not sure why it didn't indicate the lack of charge :S

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks very similar to my issue regarding a **Logitech MX Anywhere 3** Bluetooth mouse. In my case the solution was to disable the USB **auto suspend** feature of the BT controller.

Please check this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1362310/1031082

And finally a more radical workaround would be to disable the USB auto suspend feature completely via GRUB. Note, this may increase the power consumption on mobile devices.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add the following value to the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" line.

```
usbcore.autosuspend=-1
```

The result should then look like "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1". After that update the GRUB config with:

```
sudo update-grub
```